# Keep values in a row table after turning it to inputs

Tags: jquery

After inserting values in a row with a modal, I have a button to transform the cells content to inputs text. My problem is that every fields are filled with one value and not every informations typed in the modal. I also try to not transform two cells using the function not() but it changes nothing.

The row after the insert :

```
<table id="myTab">
     <tr>
        <td>name</td>
        <td>phone</td>
        <td>country</td>
        <td><dropdown id="drop1"/>...</td> 
        <td><dropdown id="drop2"/>...</td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

What I currenlty have when I click on the button :

```
<table id="myTab">
         <tr>
            <td><input type="text">name</input></td>
            <td><input type="text">name</input></td>
            <td><input type="text">name</input></td>
            <td><input type="text">name</input></td>
            <td><input type="text">name</input></td>
          </tr>
</table>
```

What I would like to get :

```
<table id="myTab">
         <tr>
            <td><input type="text">name</input></td>
            <td><input type="text">phone</input></td>
            <td><input type="text">country</input></td>
            <td><dropdown id="drop1"/>...</td>
            <td><dropdown id="drop2"/>...</td>
         </tr>
</table>
```

The piece of code :

```
function updateRow() {
//the values from the modal
  name = $("#name").val();
  phone = $("#phone").val();
  country = $("#country").val();

  $(".btn").click(function() {

    var nottarget = $("td:not(#drop1):not(#drop2)");
    var cell = $("#myTab > tbody > tr:last");

     cell.children().each(function() {
     nottarget.each(function(){

     //the inputs 
     var input = $('<input type="text" id="txtinput" value="' + name + '">');
     var input = $('<input type="text" id="txtinput" value="' + phone + '">');
     var input = $('<input type="text" id="txtinput" value="' + country + '">');

     $(this).html(input);

    });
 });
}
```

Comment: Move `name = $("#name").val();` *inside* the `$(".btn").click` handler.

Comment: Hi @Cido, I don't any dropdown id

Comment: Sorry I edited this, and I tried this solution but nothing works.

Comment: Cido: can you make sure you accepted the right answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question, you were declaring the variable `input` 3 times. Only the last definition remained and was applied for every cells.

Since you know you want the 3 first cells to be appended with an input... Let's simplify the thing by using only one loop.

Now, based on the loop `index`, it will append the right information only.

I assumed you have some values using `.val()` for name, phone and country...

Last thing... **Do not** use the same `id` more than once in a page. Notice I added numbers to `id="txtinput"`. It also could be `nameInput`... It's a good thing to use some descriptive ids.

```js
$(".btn").click(function() {
  name = "John Doh"; //$("#name").val();
  phone = "555-5678"; //$("#phone").val();
  country = "Mongolia"; //$("#country").val();

  var cell = $("#myTab tr:last td");

  cell.each(function(index) {
    if(index==0){
      var input = $('<input type="text" id="txtinput1" value="' + name + '">');
      $(this).html(input);
    }
    if(index==1){
      var input = $('<input type="text" id="txtinput2" value="' + phone + '">');
      $(this).html(input);
    }
    if(index==2){
      var input = $('<input type="text" id="txtinput3" value="' + country + '">');
      $(this).html(input);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="myTab">
  <tr>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>phone</td>
    <td>country</td>
    <td><dropdown id="drop1"/>...</td> 
    <td><dropdown id="drop2"/>...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button class="btn">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".btn").click(function() {

    var nottarget = $("td:not(#drop1, #drop2)");
    var cell = $("#myTab  tbody  tr:last");

     cell.each(function() {
     nottarget.each(function(){

     //the inputs 
     var input = $('<input type="text" id="txtinput" value="' + name + '">');
     var input = $('<input type="text" id="txtinput" value="' + phone + '">');
     var input = $('<input type="text" id="txtinput" value="' + country + '">');

     $(this).html(input);

    });
```